# Dynamically Create Models by passing name parameter Kohana 3

Tags: kohana-3

I am using the Auto_Modeler class for data access and due to the nature of my app. I would like to use ` public static function check_AMexists($fieldname,$fieldvars,$model)
{

```
$thismodel = new Model_Admin_$model();`
```

It used to work with ORM where I would simply pass the $model to ORM:factory($model).
How do I go about passing the $model variable containing the modelname in my function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$model_name = 'Model_Admin_' . $model;
$model = new $model_name;
```